# Detect MSI Installed Features By MSI Upgrade Code

Tags: windows-installer, installshield

I need to detect what features of MSI package are currently installed on the computer but I know only MSI upgrade code guid. 
Any ideas how to do this some nice way?

Thanks, 
Marek

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just migrating feature states from a previous version of the same install, you can do this by authoring the Upgrade table - fill in your Upgrade Code and version range, then set Attributes to '771' and it will copy over the feature states without removing the other installation.

If you need to do this in an unrelated app, you can do this with the [Automation Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367809%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - Use the MsiEnumRelatedProducts call to get a Product code from your Upgrade code, then use that product code with MsiEnumFeatures to get a list of features, and then with MsiQueryFeatureState to read the feature status.

Comment: Many thanks! I created another question about how to achieve this by using Automation Interface in c++. I am unable to find any reasonable tutorial on the internet. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18850008/c-application-that-uses-msi-automation-api-32-and-64bit