# C++ Application That Uses MSI Automation API 32 and 64bit

Tags: c++, com, windows-installer

I am trying to create simple c++ win32 console app(in vs2010) that calls windows installer automation api. But I am failing so far. This approach causes the "Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error at memory location" error. 
How to correctly use this api? How to make it work correctly on 32 and 64 bit system with only one .exe file? 
 
Many thanks, 
Marek

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <atlstr.h>
#import "msi.dll"

using namespace WindowsInstaller;

_bstr_t GetInstalledProduct(InstallerPtr pInstaller,_bstr_t upgradeCode){
    StringListPtr installedProducts = pInstaller->GetRelatedProducts(upgradeCode); 

    return installedProducts->Count > 0 ? installedProducts->GetItem(0) : ""; 
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    ::CoInitialize(NULL);
    InstallerPtr pInstaller("WindowsInstaller.Installer");
    _bstr_t upgradeCode("4C34BD16-CAD4-4059-B074-777793406C5F"); 
    _bstr_t installedProduct = GetInstalledProduct(pInstaller, upgradeCode); 

    StringListPtr features = pInstaller->GetFeatures(installedProduct); 

    ::CoUninitialize();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is entirely normal, the _com_error exception is raised when the COM method call fails.  Neither you nor we know why it failed until you catch the exception or stop using the smart pointer types generated by #import.  Catch the exception.

Comment: So the way I am calling the COM is correct? I added the catch (const _com_error ex) block and i received "com error scalar deleting destructor", "com error vftable". I was hoping someone could offer easy example how to work with this msi automation api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the solution. The correct way is include msi.lib in linker includes and use Msi.h from windows sdk.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <Msi.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    wchar_t productCode[255]; 
    int result = MsiEnumRelatedProducts(L"{4C34BD16-CAD4-4059-A074-777493406C5F}", 0, 0, productCode); 

    wchar_t featureName[255]; 
    wchar_t featureParent[255]; 
    MsiEnumFeatures(productCode, 0, featureName, featureParent); 

    INSTALLSTATE featureState = MsiQueryFeatureState(productCode, L"FeatureName"); 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I almost posted this but C++ isn't really my forte.  My understanding was that the Windows Installer Function reference was for C/C++ apps and that the Automation Interface was for VB6/ActiveScript languages.  I know in a C# world I use an interop library that encapsulates the functions and I avoid COM Interop whenever possible.  I stayed quite because Michael Urman is quiet the expert for this question and I had hoped he would weigh in.  I didn't want to post 'don't use COM in C++'  when I'm not really qualified to make that opinion.

Comment: Thank you anyway, I am finally able to create the major upgrade scenario for installshield suite installations with msi features. I will link this from my post http://community.flexerasoftware.com/showthread.php?207251-Advanced-UI-Suite-Detect-Installed-MSI-Features